# Is English grammar part of linguistics?

Tags: meaning

[From the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linguistics)

> Definition of linguistics: the study of human speech including the units, nature, structure, and modification of language

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grammar)

> grammar: (the study or use of) the rules about how words change their form and combine with other words to make sentences

According to those meanings above, English grammar is part of linguistics.  Is my understanding  correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Grammar`, `Syntax`, and `etymology` (to name but a few) are all separate branches of linguistics, though of course there is some overlap between them, so yes, you are correct.